# PHP code for searching for files in mySQL that have multiple kewords ("blue" AND "dress" not "blue" OR "dress"

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, keyword

Tenderfoot trying to figure out how to use multiple keywords that returns result that has all terms not just one. So "Blue Dress" search would return only files that contain both keywords not files that also contain one or the other. Where to put relevant coding into my program:

```
  $x++;

        if ($x==1)

            $construct = "concat(' ', keywords, ' ') LIKE '% $search_each %'";

        else

            $construct = "concat(' ', keywords, ' ') LIKE '% $search_each %'";

            $construct = "SELECT * FROM collection WHERE $construct";

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

$x++;

```
    if ($x==1)

        $construct = "concat(' ', keywords, ' ') LIKE '% $search_each %'";

    else

        $construct = "AND concat(' ', keywords, ' ') LIKE '% $search_each %'";

        $construct = "SELECT * FROM collection WHERE $construct";
```